# How to add a delay in a fire(new MessageEvent)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

Im really new to Java and Libgdx

I have created an interface entitled LevelQuizDialog in which the buttons will fire an event, and I want to have a 3 second delay before firing that event.

here's the code:

```
    //fire event on button click
    WrongBtn.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            CheckBtn.clearListeners();
            if(checker != answer  )
            {
                removeActor(title);
                addActor(title2);

            }

             if(checker == answer)
            {
                 removeActor(title);
                addActor(title3);
            }
            // this is the delay I had a problem with... 
             float delay = 3; // seconds

             Timer.schedule(new Task(){
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     fire(new MessageEvent(ON_CLOSE));
                 }
             }, delay);

        }
    });
}
```

I had followed a lot of tutorials in com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer
but I had a lot of errors..

I got an error in the Timer.schedule(new Task()

saying Timer is not applicable for arguments

thanks for anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1):

A portable LibGDX solution could be to use gdx-ai library which comes with a Message api that allow you to post delayed messages using a specialized event bus :

https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai/wiki/Message-Handling#dispatching-a-message

```
  messageDispatcher.dispatchMessage(
        delay,               // Immediate message if <= 0; delayed otherwise
        sender,              // It can be null
        recipient,           // It can be null, see the "Multiple Recipients" section below
        messageType,         // Any user-defined int code
        extraInfo,           // Optional data accompanying the message; it can be null
        needsReturnReceipt); // Whether the sender needs the return receipt or not
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this can help

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        fire(new MessageEvent(ON_CLOSE));       
    }
}, delayMillis);
```

Comment: you may be using wrong handler class.

   android.os.Handler().postDelayed(runnable, int)

try this.